# installation Error in Suitecrm shows undefined

Tags: database, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm trying of my level best but i can't get my solution.

The **`sugarcrm.log`** file having the following error, while i'm trying to install.

> Wed Nov 1 07:06:13 2017 [651035][-none-][FATAL] Error creating table:
>   aos_products_quotes: Query Failed: CREATE TABLE aos_products_quotes
>   (id char(36) NOT NULL ,name text NULL ,date_entered datetime NULL
>   ,date_modified datetime NULL ,modified_user_id char(36) NULL
>   ,created_by char(36) NULL ,description text NULL ,deleted bool DEFAULT
>   '0' NULL ,assigned_user_id char(36) NULL ,currency_id char(36) NULL
>   ,part_number varchar(255) NULL ,item_description text NULL ,number
>   int(11) NULL ,product_qty decimal(18,4) NULL ,product_cost_price
>   decimal(26,6) NULL ,product_cost_price_usdollar decimal(26,6) NULL
>   ,product_list_price decimal(26,6) NULL ,product_list_price_usdollar
>   decimal(26,6) NULL ,product_discount decimal(26,6) NULL
>   ,product_discount_usdollar decimal(26,6) NULL ,product_discount_amount
>   decimal(26,6) NULL ,product_discount_amount_usdollar decimal(26,6)
>   NULL ,discount varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Percentage' NULL
>   ,product_unit_price decimal(26,6) NULL ,product_unit_price_usdollar
>   decimal(26,6) NULL ,vat_amt decimal(26,6) NULL ,vat_amt_usdollar
>   decimal(26,6) NULL ,product_total_price decimal(26,6) NULL
>   ,product_total_price_usdollar decimal(26,6) NULL ,vat varchar(100)
>   DEFAULT '5.0' NULL ,parent_type varchar(255) NULL ,parent_id char(255)
>   NULL ,product_id char(36) NULL ,group_id char(36) NULL , PRIMARY KEY
>   (id), KEY idx_aospq_par_del (parent_id, parent_type, deleted))
>   CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci: MySQL error 1071:
>   Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Note that issue is related to MySql configuration. If you google mysql error (MySQL error 1071) then you will find very useful information. Anyhow try followings:

Execute following query before creating or altering table:

```
SET @@global.innodb_large_prefix = 1;
```

It will set max key length to *3072 bytes*

Comment: I'm also tried that @star But My shared hosting server Executive told that not possible to Global setting

Comment: You need to know that SuiteCRM is not shared hosting friendly.